# Duplicidade de e-mail usando Mail() do PHP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Preciso de ajuda, não sei onde está o erro para gerar duplicidade de e-mail somente para o $to. Segue abaixo meu código:

```
$mails = 'emailcopia@teste.com.br';
$Nome = 'Fulano';
$Email = 'teste@teste.com.br';

        $to      = 'recebo@teste.com.br';
        $subject = 'teste';
        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $message = 'mensagem minha mensagem';

        $headers .= 'From: '.$Nome.'<'.$Email.'>'. "\r\n";
        if ($mails != ''){
            $headers .= 'Cc: '.$mails.''. "\r\n";
        }
        $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP'."\r\n"; //mailer
        $headers .= 'X-Priority: 3'."\r\n"; //1 UrgentMessage, 3 Normal
        /*$headers .= 'Return-Path: '.$Email.''."\r\n"*/;
        $headers .= 'Reply-to: '.$Email.''."\r\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        echo "true";
        exit(); // coloquei pra ver se matava algum loop, mais não deu certo porque não tem loop nenhum.
```

obs: coloquei e-mails fake

Comment: Wilson, como o `exit();` não funcionou, tenta criar uma variável, e faz uma verificação do tipo `if(envia){mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); envia = false;}` p/ confirmar que realmente não é nenhum loop.

Comment: Essa função mail, é nativa ou você mantém o código? Se for código da sua aplicação, poderia colocar os trechos relevantes na pergunta?

Comment: Atualize sua pergunta informando o erro exato que seu código apresenta.

Comment: O código que apresentei é fidedigno ao que estou usando, não está envolvido em nenhum laço/loop, porém como esta ocorrendo duplicidade ao receber o e-mail eu coloquei um exit() para que não ocorra mais de 1 vez, mas o exit() nem estava no meu código de início e nem faz efeito agora. Quanto a mensagem de erro ele não gera, ele somente duplica o recebimento do e-mail na caixa de entrada do webmail.

Comment: Agradeço a todos pela ajuda, já resolvi o problema. O e-mail configurado na variavel $To recebia cópia de todos os e-mails do domínio, então quando enviava uma cópia para outro e-mail ele recebia uma nova cópia do e-mail. Solução: retirei ele do $To e funcionou. Se for possível colegas podem encerrar/fechar este post. Obrigado